# Relax or disable table constraints when using Dapper and Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, .net-4.0, edmx, dapper

I would like to set a do something like this `dataSet1.EnforceConstraints = false;` using the Dapper.Net ORM and Entity Framework.

I created the models in VS2010 where a property:

```
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String ethnicname
    {
        get
        {
            return _ethnicname;
        }
        set
        {
            OnethnicnameChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("ethnicname");
            _ethnicname = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, false);
            ReportPropertyChanged("ethnicname");
            OnethnicnameChanged();
        }
    }
```

... when `value` is `null`, I get a constraint exception at `StructuralObject.SetValidValue...` .  How and where do I turn this off?

My data call looks like this:

```
    public DAL.Models.PROFILE GetProfile(int profileID)
    {
        using (IDbConnection connection = OpenConnection("MyDBConnectionString"))
        {
            try
            {

                var profiles = connection.Query<DAL.Models.PROFILE>("SELECT * FROM PROFILES WHERE ID=@ID", new { ID = profileID }); // IEnumerable
                var profile = profiles.First<DAL.Models.PROFILE>();

                return profile;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorLogging.Instance.Fatal(ex);
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using Dapper *and* EF at the same time?

Comment: Yes.  I used EF to generate the classes, and Dapper for the calls, all inside a WCF web service.  Seems to be choking though.  Suggestions?  (probably the topic for a new question)

Comment: Why don't you just create plain POCO classes yourself and get rid of EF?

Comment: I'm using the DbContext Generator for EF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using autogenerated `EntityObject` based entities and you mark field as not nullable (your database has it not nullable) you cannot turn this validation off. The second parameter of `SetValidValue` decides if null is allowed or not.

Comment: Right.  In the db the fields are nullable, but for some reason, when the class is generated this is set to false, and should be true.  I would rather not have to edit these after class generation.

Comment: You can control if the property is nullable or not in the designer (EDMX).

Comment: Thank you... found it.  It was a bit confusing as I thought I had to modify a certain table's properties.  Turns out the issue was in a complex type generated from a sproc.